# How to upgrade gradle version?

Tags: android, android-studio

Here I face lots of problems while importing an application to my android studio.

it require to upgrade gradle version.

Comment: In your project's main build.gradle(not in app build.gradle) try to change in dependencies with required updated gradle version classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Comment: Thanks alot It was usefull

Answer (score 0):

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

open the app and select the gradle>gradle_wrapper.properties and check the distrubution url then only change the gradle version like that https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.1-bin.zip
and click to sync process then it will be works
...........................